# Spinner items selection radio missing

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, android-arrayadapter

When my items contains English and/or numeric signs, it shows the radio selection near the item, but when it doesn't contains any English and/or numeric signs (contains only Hebrew in my example) it does not show the radio selection near the item.

For the adapters (array adapter) creation i used the layout "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item"

And before setting the Spinner adapter I did

```
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The solution I found for now, is set the layout to "simple_dropdown_item_1line"; this solves the problem by not showing the radio button.

Any ideas on how to get the radio button visible always?

---

correction - the solution does not work. for **few** of my spinners it shows a white text on a white background.

Answer (score 7):

Hi the below code works for me in hebrew

For the Adapter use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

and `myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);`

Regards,
Yaron

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to get the radio button visible always?

Use an appropriate layout for the drop-down view resource. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` should always work. If you create your own layout, and it does not work, identify where you changed things from `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` that would affect matters (e.g., text color, background color).